# Delete cookies from .domain.com in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have cookies that I want to delete using PHP. I can read cookies from `.domain.tld` from the `$_COOKIES` variable, but I can't delete them. I tried deleting them from `domain.tld` and `subdomain.domain.tld`, but neither worked. How can I delete cookies from `.domain.tld`?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
setcookie($k,'',time()-60*60*24,'/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
$past = time() - 86400; 
setcookie($k, '', $past, "/", ".domain.tld");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  setcookie('cookie_name', null, -1, '/');
  setcookie($k, null, -1, '/');
```